# Let $\alpha:S^n\rightarrow S^n$ be the antipodal map. Why is $\alpha \not\simeq id$ if $n$ is even?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I defined the homotopy $H:S^n\times [0,1]\rightarrow S^n$ as $H(x,t)=-x+t2x$. Why does this function not define a homotopy?

Answer (score 4):

Because, for instance, $H\left(x,\frac12\right)=0$ and $0\notin S^n$.

Comment: You must map continuously through elements in the spaces? The definition I have for homotopy left that ambiguous. Can functions that are homotopic have disjoint images?

Comment: That's the definition of a *map*. A map $f\colon A\to B$ has $f(a)\in B$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: You wrote $H\colon S^n\times[0,1]\longrightarrow S^n$ yourself!

Comment: @Colebasaur There is a difference between a homotopy between two maps $S^n\to \Bbb R^{n+1}$ and a homotopy between two maps $S^n\to S^n$. For the former, yes, you have found a homotopy. For the latter, though, there is no homotopy for even $n$. For two maps $f, g:X\to Y$, a homotopy $H$ from $f$ to $g$ must have its entire image contained in $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

To give a hint for the question in the title:

Cosinder the degree of the identity map and the antipodal map. If you can show that these two do $\textbf{not}$ agree, then you have shown that $\alpha \not\simeq \text{id}$ (why?).